# Best fluent NHibernate configuration for Azure SQL V12?

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, azure-sql-database

I am looking to configure Fluent NHibernate with Azure SQL V12. In the various posts online that I have seen, the configuration seems to be using `MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008`. If I understand it correctly, the newer `MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012` should make use of some of the new features in SQL Server 2012+. Could you please advise if this works correctly without issues? Could you please point me at some documentation if available or provide full session factory configuration for comparison?

I have tested this basic configuration which seems to be ok with simple SQL statements:

```
var sessionfactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(_databaseSettings.ConnectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<TestEntity>()
                .Where(a => a.Namespace.EndsWith("Entities"))
                .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<TestEntityMappingOverride>()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I am using `FluentNHibernate version="2.0.3.0"`and `NHibernate version="4.0.4.4000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update for those who are still interested, the configuration close to the one shown in the question has been working in a production without issues.